# How can I group different rows based on its value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge

I have a data frame in `pandas` like this:

| Attributes1 | Attributes value1 | Attributes2 | Attributes value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | b | 4 |
| b | 2 | a | 5 |

Does anyone know how can I get a new data frame like below?

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(
    df.apply(
        lambda x: dict(
            zip(x.filter(regex=r"Attributes\d+$"), x.filter(like="value"))
        ),
        axis=1,
    ).to_list()
)

print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  5  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [transpose()](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-t-transpose/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20T%20attribute%20or,columns%20swapped%20(%3D%20transposed%20object).) function to transpose the rows to columns, then use the [groupby()](https://datascientyst.com/combine-multiple-columns-into-single-one-in-pandas/) function to group the columns with the same name.

Also, in the future, please add what you've tried to do to solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can do `wide_to_long` then `pivot`

```
s = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                    ['Attributes','Attributes value'], 
                    i = 'index',
                    j = 'a').reset_index().drop(['a'],axis=1)
s = s.pivot(*s)
Out[22]: 
Attributes  a  b
index           
0           1  4
1           5  2
```